# MSRDP.OCX is not registered as component in vb6

Tags: vb6

Can Anyone guide me how can add MSRDP.OCX in my VB6 Project. I tried to add MSRDP.OCX as ActiveX Component. MSRDP.OCX is not registerable as an ActiveX Control. How ever I registered it using regsvr32 command.

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/failure-add-msrdp-ocx-control-c-net-vbulletin-net-form-t1390222.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is already registered, just look through the components list to find it. If it's not, or to help you find it, run Visual Basic as an admin (of on Vista/Windows 7) and use the browse on the components dialog.

Comment: I am using windows xp. I registered the file through regsvr32 command. then tried to add this registered ocx file by browsing it in Component. It gave me error message as "MSRDP.OCX is not registerable as an ActiveX Control" and not included in Component.